# Binding libaums AAR in a Xamarin Android project

Tags: android, xamarin, bind, aar

I did a binding of libaums AAR in my Xamarin Android solution in Visual Studio.
I used `libaums-0.5.0.aar` from [here](https://bintray.com/package/files/mjdev/maven/libaums?order=asc&sort=name&basePath=com%2Fgithub%2Fmjdev%2Flibaums%2F0.5.0&tab=files).

At compile time I got 2 errors that I solved by adding those directives to my `Metadata.xml` file:

```
&lt;attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory']" name="managedReturn"&gt;IUsbFile&lt;/attr&gt;

&lt;attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile']" name="managedReturn"&gt;IUsbFile&lt;/attr&gt;
```

Then I tried to implement the example found on the libaums github to get the mass storage devices:

```
            UsbMassStorageDevice[] devices = UsbMassStorageDevice.GetMassStorageDevices(Global.MyActivity.ApplicationContext);

            foreach (UsbMassStorageDevice device in devices)
            {

                // before interacting with a device you need to call init()!
                device.Init();

                // Only uses the first partition on the device
                IFileSystem currentFs = device.Partitions[0].FileSystem;

                Console.WriteLine("Capacity: " + currentFs.Capacity);
                Console.WriteLine("Occupied Space: " + currentFs.OccupiedSpace);
                Console.WriteLine("Free Space: " + currentFs.FreeSpace);
                Console.WriteLine("Chunk size: " + currentFs.ChunkSize);
            }
```

But at run time I have an exception on `currentFs.Capacity` which says:

> no non-static method "Lcom/github/mjdev/libaums/fs/fat32/Fat32FileSystem;getCapacity()J"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How did you manage to get that aar compiled with your metadata set? I had to add the folowing to metadata.xml to get it compiled:

```
<metadata>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="visibility">public override</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="final">true</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedReturn">IUsbFile</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="visibility">public override</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="final">true</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedReturn">IUsbFile</attr>
</metadata>
```

Why? For example, without this, after transpiling the method CreateDirectory(string) has the signature `public virtual unsafe global::Com.Github.Mjdev.Libaums.FS.Fat32.FatFile CreateFile (string p0)`. But it has to be `public override unsafe IUsbFile CreateFile (string p0)`. Changing `final` to true appears to remove the virtual modifyer (seems to be a bug?).

Concerning your exception, have you tried to use a newer library? [Here](https://bintray.com/package/files/mjdev/maven/libaums?order=asc&sort=name&basePath=com%2Fgithub%2Fmjdev%2Flibaums%2F0.5.5&tab=files) you can download the 0.5.5 version.

Comment: My medataset only needs the 2 lines from my first post to compile and to solve the exception I had, I had to do some modifications in the libaums Java source code. I am using libaums version 0.5.2 now.

Comment: Could you update the libaums source code modifications in your post?